# Can any one tell me why this Jquery code does not respond right?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to do simple X O game ,it seems to work just fine but when i reach the 3 "Os"
the function  call() ,it does not give me you loose in the if statement
,it does give you win wehn i reach 3 "Xs" .

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript" >



    function call() {
        var x = Math.floor((Math.random() * 9) + 1);
        if ($('#td' + x).text() === "x" || $('#td' + x).text() === "o") {
            call();
        }

        else if (check() === true) {
            $('div').text("You win ");
            return false;
        }

        else if (checkLoose() === true) {
        $('p').text("You Loose ");
            return false;
        }

        else
            $('#td' + x).text("o");
        }



    function win(as, bs, cc) {
        return ($('#td'+as).text() === "x" && $('#td'+bs).text() === "x" && $('#td'+cc).text() === "x") ;

    }

    function check(){

        if (win(1, 2, 3) || win(1, 4, 7) || win(4, 5, 6) || win(7, 8, 9) || win(2, 5, 8) || win(3, 6, 9) || win(1, 5, 9) || win(3, 5, 7) === true) 
              return true;
 }

 function checkLoose() {

     if (lose(1, 2, 3) || lose(1, 4, 7) || lose(4, 5, 6) || lose(7, 8, 9) || lose(2, 5, 8) || lose(3, 6, 9) || lose(1, 5, 9) || lose(3, 5, 7) === true) {

         return true;
     } 
 }




    function lose(as, bs, cc) {
        return ($('#td' + as).text() === "o" && $('#td' + bs).text() === "o" && $('#td' + cc).text() === "o");

    }

    function dsd(sad) {

        if ($('#td' + sad).text() === "x" || $('#td' + sad).text() === "o")
            return false;

        else if (check() === true)
            return false;

        else if (checkLoose() === true) {

            return false;
        }
        else {
            $("#td" + sad).text("x");
            call();
        }       
        }

        $(document).ready(function(){
        $("td").hover(function () {
            $(this).css("background-color", "yellow");
        }, function () {
            $(this).css("background-color", "white");
        });
    });

</script>

</head>
<body>




<center>
<h1 >"        X ,O Game    "</h1><br />
<div></div>
<p></p>
<table>
    <tr>
       <td id="td1"  onclick="dsd(1);" ></td>
       <td id="td2" onclick="dsd(2);"></td>
       <td id="td3" onclick="dsd(3);"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
       <td id="td4" onclick="dsd(4);"></td>
       <td id="td5" onclick="dsd(5);"></td>
       <td id="td6" onclick="dsd(6);"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
       <td id="td7" onclick="dsd(7);"></td>
       <td id="td8" onclick="dsd(8);"></td>
       <td id="td9" onclick="dsd(9);"</td>
    </tr>
</table>
</center>
```

Comment: `checkloose` must be `checkLoose` uppercase

Comment: Need to post what those function do and any associated HTML.

Comment: ["Lose"](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/lose) is not spelled ["Loose"](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/loose)... look them up.

Answer (score 1):

Your check (and checkLoose) are only called during the click.
You need to check for wins and losses after the line that you add o's inside your call() function.

```
$('#td' + x).text("o");
/* add calls to check() and checkLoose() here */
```

Answer (score 0):

In function call, you check for the winner/loser before adding the "o" letter to the cell (which causes checkLoose from not returning true). If you add it earlier, checkLoose will return true (and the game will update properly)

There is a side effect, however, of moving it up: If the human wins, the computer will still add an "o" (however, the game will say "You win" still) - You can address this in a variety of ways. I'll let you figure that one out :)